# Add Column to DataFrame With Aggregated Values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame as follows

```
profDF
+---+------------+---------+------+
| ID|        Name|      Occ|Salary|
+---+------------+---------+------+
|  1|       James|Detective| 30000|
|  2|      Victor| Salesman| 50000|
|  3|       Doris|      CEO| 20000|
+---+------------+---------+------+
```

I want to add a new column that contains the difference between the maximum Salary and the Salary of each person.

```
+---+------------+---------+------+-------+
| ID|        Name|      Occ|Salary|DiffMax|
+---+------------+---------+------+-------+
|  1|       James|Detective| 30000|  20000|
|  2|      Victor| Salesman| 50000|      0|
|  3|       Doris|      CEO| 20000|  30000|
+---+------------+---------+------+-------+
```

One way to do this would be create another DF by doing a `groupBy("ID")` and `max` and then join this DF with `persDF` on "ID" but `groupBy` would not give me the max Salary of **all** the rows.

Another way would be to use `withColumn("DiffMax", ...)`. But I can't seem to be able to find out the second parameter to `withColumn` that would give me the desired result.

Could someone help me with this? I'm using Spark-1.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. Find the `max` Salary and then using `withColumn` find the difference between existing Salary and this `max` Salary.

```
val maxSalary = profDF.agg(max(profDF("Salary"))).first().get(0)

profDF.withColumn("DiffMax", lit(maxSalary) - profDF("Salary")).show()

//output

+---+------+---------+------+-------+
| ID|  Name|      Occ|Salary|DiffMax|
+---+------+---------+------+-------+
|  1| James|Detective| 30000|20000.0|
|  2|Victor| Salesman| 50000|    0.0|
|  3| Doris|      CEO| 20000|30000.0|
+---+------+---------+------+-------+
```